# Structural error property type should be equal to one of the allowed values allowedValues: string, number, boolean, integer, array in Swagger editor

Tags: swagger-2.0

I'm using springfox 2.9.2 and want test my swagger JSON as YAML in https://editor.swagger.io/

I have property with `@ApiParam` annotation `type: object`

```
@ApiParam(value = "metadata file")

protected Object metadataFile;
```

but when I test my generated json on swagger editor I got this error:

> Structural error at ---.parameters.5.type should be equal to one of
> the allowed values allowedValues: string, number, boolean, integer,
> array Jump to line ---

there is way to allowed property type object in this section?

the section that trigger the problem

paths:

:

```
post:

  parameters:

      name: metadataFile
      in: query
      description: ...
      required: false
      type: object
```

Comment: Can you please post the part of your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file that triggers this error?

Answer (score 1):

Swagger documentation (go to the bottom of the page): https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/

"Can I have an object as a query parameter?
This is possible in OpenAPI 3.0, but not in 2.0."

Answer (score 0):

it is worth considering to remake the endpoint on the POST. Send parameters in the body

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).